# How do I cast a void pointer to struct type?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, structure

So I want to know what can I do to type cast a void pointer to a struct type.

Code-

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct man {
    int age;
    int var;
};

struct woman {
    char c;
    int age;
    int var;
};

void *ptr;

struct man mlist[2];
struct woman wlist[2];

struct man *mptr = mlist;    //mptr points to first element of mlist
struct woman *wptr = wlist;

int function(int gender, int a, int b)   ///a,b are for struct
{
    if (gender == 1)
    {
        (struct man *)ptr = mptr;
        //ptr = (struct man *)ptr;
        //ptr = (struct man *)mptr;
    }
    else
    {
        (struct woman *)ptr = wptr;
        //ptr = (struct woman *)ptr;
    }
    ptr->age = a;      //dont know if man or woman
    ptr->var = b;     
    
    return (ptr->age + ptr->var);   
}

void main(void) 
{
    printf("\n%d\n", function(1, 10, 3));
}
```

I get the error saying `error: request for member 'age' in something not a structure or union` and `error: request for member 'var' in something not a structure or union` and the warnings
`warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer 38 |     ptr->var=b;`

I have tried several ways of type casting the `void` pointer `*ptr`, but to no avail. I would like to solve this in this way because this is a prototype of a bigger program.

If there are some concepts that I might be missing feel free to correct me, I am relatively new to programming.

I have tried to type cast in such manner :

`ptr = (struct man *)mptr;`
`(struct man *)ptr = mptr;`
`ptr = mptr;`
`ptr = (struct man *)ptr;`

but the error persists.

Edit: I am aware of the `((struct man *)ptr)->age` solution ,but I would have to replace it everywhere, in fact `((struct woman *)ptr)->age` also works.

struct data alignment is also not a problem as I have tried with identical structs.

**My main question is what is preventing the `void *ptr` not getting type casted in the `if`/`else` statements**

Comment: Generally `function` would take a `void*` and interpret it as either a `struct man *` or `struct woman *` depending on `int gender`, and then do things depending on that. If this is for a class, you should talk to your teaching staff.

Comment: ((struct man *)ptr)->age

Comment: @JohnFilleau  that is exactly what is not happening. It is not getting type casted to either `struct man *` or `struct woman *`. The error tells it is still of void * type

Comment: @SvenNilsson   I cannot replace every mentioning of `ptr` with '((struct man *)ptr)'.  I just wanted to know what went wrong type casting in the if/else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

With your structure it's not possible. The offset of the variables inside the structures are different, you can't have a single generic pointer that can point to either of the structures.

Instead I suggest you create a common structure used by both your structures, which is placed first in the two structures. It will kind of emulate inheritance in object oriented languages.

So change to e.g.

```
struct common_data
{
    unsigned age;  // Unsigned, since age can't be negative
    int var;
};

struct man
{
    struct common_data common;
};

struct woman
{
    struct common_data common;
    char c;
};
```

Now you can use a pointer to either of the structures as a pointer to the common structure:

```
struct common_data *common;

if (gender == 1)
{
    common = (struct common_data *) mptr;
}
else
{
    common = (struct common_data *) wptr;
}

common->age = a;
common->var = b;
```

Comment: Suggestion: `common = &mptr->common;` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but alignment of the data inside the structure is not causing the problem. I have tried with the same data types in the same order for struct man and struct woman and it still did not work. I was wondering what went wrong trying to type cast the void pointer.

Comment: @Kuroro It *is* a problem. And you simply can't dereference a `void *` pointer without casting it to the type it actually points to. So you must have an explicit cast of `ptr` to `struct man *` or to `struct woman *` (for example `((struct man *) ptr)->age`). So that kind of defeats the point of using a generic pointer to access common data. Though to be honest, by using explicit cast to the correct structure will make the offset issue moot.

Comment: @Kuroro: This answer does not say the alignment is causing your problem directly. It says a solution with those structures as they are is impossible due to the alignment. Your immediate problem is that C has no run-time dynamic typing except for variably modified types (types involving arrays of lengths specified at run-time). It does not support a pointer that can be directly used to access different types of objects. The various attempts you show in the question are fundamentally incompatible with how C works. Use the solution in this answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil    So just to clarify, I cannot type cast the `void * ptr` in the if/else block and call it a day. Could you please explain  what is going on  exactly here.

Comment: @Kuroro: C does not have dynamic typing. When `x->y` is used in a C program, the type of `x` **must** be known at the moment it is compiled. It cannot be a pointer that might refer to one type of structure or another type of structure. The C implementation **will not** choose the structure type when the program is executing. It does not matter how you declare it, what casts you do, or how you assign a value to `x`. In the expression `x->y`, `x` has a specific type determined when it is compiled. Period. That is how the C language works.